# Induction divisibility

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Show that for any k∈N, if $2^{3k-1} +5\cdot3^k$ is divisible by 11 then, $2^{3^{(k+2)-1}} +5\cdot3^{k+2}$ is divisible by 11.

Base Case: k = 2

$\implies2^{3*2-1} +\cdot3^2 =77$

Since 77 is divisible by 11, the base case holds true

I.H: Assume it is true for  $2^{3x-1} +5\cdot3^x$,x∈N

Then; for k=x+1

$$\implies 2^{3(x+1)-1} +5\cdot3^{x+1}$$
$$\implies 2^{3x-1}\cdot2^3 +5\cdot(3^x\cdot3^1)$$
$$\implies 2^{3x-1}\cdot8 +15\cdot3^x$$

How do i proceed from what i have so far, also what variable do i use since k is already been used?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is prove for any even natural $k$ prove that $11$ divides $2^{3k -1} + 5*3^k$.

*That* is a proper induction statement.

Base case: $k = 2$ then $2^{3*2 - 1} + 5*3^2 = 2^5 + 5*9 = 32 + 45 = 77$.

Inductions step.  Assume $11$ divides $2^{3k -1} + 5*3^k$ show $11$ divides $2^{3(k+2) -1} + 5*3^{k+2}$.

$2^{3(k+2) -1} + 5*3^{k+2} = 2^{3k-1}*2^6 + 5*3^k*9= 9(2^{3k-1} + 5*3^k) + 2^{3k-1}(2^6 - 9) = 9(2^{3k-1} + 5*3^k) + 55*2^{3k-1}$.  So $11$ divides $2^{3k-1} + 5*3^k$ and $11$ divides $55$ then $11$ divides $9(2^{3k-1} + 5*3^k) + 55*2^{3k-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $2^{3k-1}+5\cdot3^k\equiv0\pmod{11}\iff2^{3k}+10\cdot3^k\equiv0\cdot2\iff8^k-3^k\equiv0$

which is true if only if $k$ is even

If $f(k)=2^{3k-1}+5\cdot3^k,$

$f(n+2)-3^2f(n)=2^{3(n+2)-1}+5\cdot3^{n+2}-3^2(2^{3n-1}+5\cdot3^n)=2^{3n-1}(2^6-9)\equiv0\pmod{11}$

$\implies f(n+2)\equiv3^2f(n)$

$\implies11\mid f(n+2)\iff11\mid f(n)$

Alternatively, find $$f(n+2)-(2^3)^2\cdot f(n)$$

Answer (score 0):

Another method

$A_{2k}=4*2^{6k-3}+15*3^{2k-1}≡4*(8^{2k-1}+3^{2k-1})$

$=4*(11-3)^{2k-1}+4*3^{2k-1}\equiv
0 \mod 11$